# Integrating DTedit with "new row" ActionButton

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to append rows to a dtedit object using a seperate actionbutton. The button creates a row and I want it appended to the dtedit table. 
I have it working so that this all happens, but the dtedit function doesn't seem to recognize the data, because when I try using the "Edit" button that's built in, the fields don't pre-populate in the modal as they should.

I have included a reproducible example below. You will see that the "Add Row" functionality works, but when you click on a row and press edit, the modal does not recognize the data.

*Edited with `DTedit` package load and the removal of `view.label.cols`

```
devtools::install_github('jbryer/DTedit')
library(DTedit)

ui <- fluidPage(
      actionButton('addrow', "New Row"),
      uiOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame('Order' = integer(), 'Category' = character(), 'Name' = character(), stringsAsFactors = F)
  table.reactive <- reactiveVal(df)
  dtedit(input, output,
         name = 'table',
         thedata = df,
         edit.cols = c('Order', 'Category', 'Name'),
         edit.label.cols = c('Order', 'Category', 'Name'),
         input.types = c( Order = 'numericInput',
                          Category='textInput',
                          Name='textInput'
         ),
         view.cols = c('Order', 'Category', 'Name'),
         callback.update = plandrill.update.callback,
         callback.insert = plandrill.insert.callback,
         callback.delete = plandrill.delete.callback,
         show.copy = F, show.insert = F)

  dt.proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("tabledt")

  ## append row
  observeEvent(input$addrow, {
    row <- data.frame(nrow(table.reactive()) + 1, "ABC", "DEF", stringsAsFactors = F)
    appended_table = rbind(table.reactive(), row)
    table.reactive(appended_table)
    replaceData(dt.proxy,
               appended_table,
               rownames = FALSE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your example is not runnable: where is `dtedit()` defined?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila thank you, I updated the code to ensure its runnable

Answer (score 1):

`jbryer/DTedit` makes a local copy of the dataframe passed through the `thedata` argument, and stores it internally in `results$thedata`. `results$thedata` is used for subsequent datatable editing and is *not* changed by `replaceData`.

The effect you require *can* be achieved through a [modified version of `DTedit`](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit/pull/5), which I wrote (with the help of others) and is [available on Github at `DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit`](https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit).

```
library(DTedit)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('addrow', "New Row"),
  uiOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- data.frame('Order' = integer(),
                   'Category' = character(),
                   'Name' = character(),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
  table.reactive <- reactiveVal(df)
  dtedit(input, output,
         name = 'table',
         thedata = table.reactive,
         edit.cols = c('Order', 'Category', 'Name'),
         edit.label.cols = c('Order', 'Category', 'Name'),
         input.types = c( Order = 'numericInput',
                          Category='textInput',
                          Name='textInput'
         ),
         view.cols = c('Order', 'Category', 'Name'),
         # callback.update = plandrill.update.callback,
         # callback.insert = plandrill.insert.callback,
         # callback.delete = plandrill.delete.callback,
         show.copy = F, show.insert = F)
  
  dt.proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("tabledt")
  
  ## append row
  observeEvent(input$addrow, {
    row <- data.frame(Order = nrow(table.reactive()) + 1,
                      Category = "ABC",
                      Name = "DEF",
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
    appended_table = rbind(table.reactive(), row)
    table.reactive(appended_table)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this version of `DTedit`, the dataframe is passed as a `reactiveVal` (`table.reactive`), and `DTedit`'s copy changes when `table.reactive` changes.

I needed to disable defining the various callbacks in your example, as the callbacks were not defined. I also need to be explicit about labeling the columns in the `row` dataframe.

Further examples can be seen [in a vignette](https://rpubs.com/DavidFong/DTedit), and linked through [README.md on Github](https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit).